# overloaded stream extraction operator error

Tags: c++

how do you assign extraction operator to a linked list class.

```
struct Node{
    int x;
    Node *next;
  }*p;
```

and here is my function

```
istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, list &l){
  is>>l;
  return is;
}
```

and this doesn't work, it gives me a segmentation error
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00007fff5f3ffff8
0x000000010000127b in operator>> ()

Comment: I'd expect a stack overflow from that. You're calling the function recursively. You get to decide what it does (e.g., input a list of comma-separated values and parse them into a new list).

Comment: That's impossible to answer without knowing what `list` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code causes an *infinite recursion*. It basically says that extracting a `list` from a `std::istream` is done by extracting a `list` from a `std::istream`.